# jqgrid inside a Jquery simplemodal working but i cannot see the column header names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, simplemodal

When i use jqgrid inside a Jquery simplemodal it works but i cannot see the column header names(colNames). Rows are displayed ok but no column header ,do you know what can cause this ?

```
$("#basic").modal({
   onShow: function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        data: items,
        datatype: 'local',
        width: 650,
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 25,
        colNames: [
              ' '
            , ' '
            , 'Column 3'
            , 'Column 4'

            ],
        colModel: [
            {
            name: 'IsSelected', index: 'IsSelected', width: 30,
            align: 'center',
            formatter: 'checkbox',
            editoptions: { value: '1:0' },
            formatoptions: { disabled: false }
            }
            , { name: 'col1', index: 'col1'}
            , { name: 'col2', index: 'col2'}
            , { name: 'col3', index: 'col3', width: 200}
            , { name: 'col4', index: 'col4'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Make a fiddle. It may have something to do with CSS/HTML...
Basically, we need more info on your current setup.